# is there an api to access a list of tags on super user?

Tags: discussion

As above, is there an api function to access a list of tags on super user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course there is, have a look to [/tags](http://api.superuser.com/1.0/help/method?method=tags) route documentation.

> **Summary**
>   Gets the tags on all questions, along with their usage counts.

Give it a [try](http://api.superuser.com/1.0/tags).